# Does popular worship of Lord Shiva in Northern India comes under any Shaiva sect or is it Advatic/Smartha by nature?

Tags: shiva, advaita, shaivism, kashmiri-shaivism, shaiva-siddhanta

We know Saiva Siddhanta,(a dualistic Shaiva sect) and Veer Shaiva,(another dualistic Shaiva sect) exists in south, I don't think there are any such sects in north India. Except maybe Kashmir Shaivism, which itself is not much popular here. Regardless Shiva worship is very popular in north too.

So my question is does this popular worship of Shiva comes under any sect of Shaivism. Like worship of Vishnu/Rama/Krishna and His forms in North comes under various sampradays like Ramanandi,Gaudiya,Nimbarka,Haridasa,Vallabha etc. If so which agamas are followed in famous temples like Kashi Vishwanath and others? Does it comes under a sect of Shaivism or it's just Advatic/Smartha by nature?

Comment: Shaiva Siddhanta is qualified non dualism, not dualism.